# Display the device camera's input inside an AR environment

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, arcore

I have an application (that is created by Unity) for android that displays a 3D Portal on your touch location and once the portal is places there is a sphere behind it that plays a 360 video and once you move inside the portal you can look around and explore the environment.

However, I've been trying to also show the input from the device camera inside the 3D world with no luck.
I have tried the following:

1. Adding a RawImage and displaying the camera's input behind the portal but then I had to add the RawImage to the main camera which stops acting like an AR camera (i.e. when you move around nothing happens the portal just remains as a static object)
2. Adding a different camera and displaying the RawImage to that different camera which resulted the exact same way as the point above.

So, right now I'm really clueless and I can't find any topics or information about how to display a camera's input inside an AR environment any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks a lot.